# нужно получить сегодняшнюю дату, перевести ее в String и потом обратно в дату

Tags: java, строки, дата

Помогите уменьшить код, нужно получить сегодняшнюю дату, перевести ее в Стринг и потом обратно в дату

```
Date dateNow                      = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatForDateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String date                       = formatForDateNow.format(dateNow);               
Date d                            = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(date);

System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: можно все одной строчкой в консоль вывести

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Date dateNow = new Date();
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(dateNow));
System.out.println(d);
```